# Exercise from Theorem of Implicit Function's chapter

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$(x^2+y^4)f(x,y)+f(x,y)^3=1$$ for any $(x,y) \in U$. Prove that $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must show that there are no singular points for
$$
F(x,y,z)=z^3+(x^2+y^4)z-1
$$
where simultaneously $F=0$ and $0=\partial_zF$.

Then the implicit function theorem tells you that the solution $z=f(x,y)$ is as smooth as the defining function $F$.